# Fresh Weblate installation: ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'

Tags: python, celery, gunicorn, weblate

I installed Weblate==3.10 on my Debian based system within a VirtualEnv and Python 3.5

If I run Weblate with the command =>

```
weblate runserver
```

The development server starts and everything works fine.

But if I try to run the project with gunicorn I get an import error.

```
pwd
/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weblate
gunicorn wsgi:weblate
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22587] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22587] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (22587)
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22587] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22590] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22590
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22590] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weblate/wsgi.py", line 45, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weblate/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weblate.celery import app as celery_app
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weblate/celery.py", line 26, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weblate/celery.py", line 26, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22590] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22590)
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22587] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-01-02 09:26:09 +0000] [22587] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Not sure if this is a bug. I guess I am missing something. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `PYTHONPATH` for gunicorn contains `/var/www/ws5weblate/priv/weblate-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weblate` which it should not include.